# iPhone cocos2d game: test version is different from appstore version

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, positioning

At test version there is no problem, even at ad-hoc version. But at appstore downloaded version there are positioning problem. For example CCMenu does not showing it's items at correct place.
Please if anyone has any idea, help me!!!

Or how can I test the app, exported for appstore, without waiting for approval??

Comment: Are you building it correctly for debug or release?

Comment: I think there is no problem with building. One week ago app was updated, but we found bug and we needed to update. We added only 3 images, and uploaded again. But we used xcode 4.2, before we were using 4.0.

Comment: So, to confirm you have fully tested the release version on device?

Comment: The same problem with me, debug mode, ad hoc mode are ok. But upload to app store has problem? Do you find the root cause? Please share

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, click Edit Scheme in the drop down near the Play button. Then on the left side of that window, check under Archive and see if it says Release. If it does, then an app you build out for ad-hoc distribution to yourself or testers should be the same build that you sent to App Store (if you don't make any changes between, of course).

Comment: Thanks for answer. "release" is selected. But adhoc version has no problem, wierd.